# c# html file encoding iso-8859-2

Tags: c#

I have this html file: http://mek.oszk.hu/17700/17789/17789.htm, which I already downloaded.

This html file has iso-8859-2 charset.

I want to convert this HTML file to a PDF file with IronPdf nuget package.

**I tried this, but It doesn't work:**

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(book.Source,Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2")))
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.Load(stream);
    var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
    var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
    var OutputPath = "HtmlToPDF.pdf";
    PDF.SaveAs(OutputPath);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputPath);
}
```

**My output result:** [image]

**UPDATE 1**: I want to this output result:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  You're getting PDF output, aren't you?  *How* is it not working?

Comment: @Amy The convert is working. As you can see in the picture the encoding doesn't work. I Updated my question.

Comment: `book.Source` is encoded in utf8, not 8859-2.  You did provide any info to guess how that happened, but consider to not fix that.

Comment: If you get multiple characters per character you want, it's indeed a safe bet it's a UTF encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's Magyar :) but obtained a better result with this piece of code:

```
            var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
            var PDF = Renderer.StaticRenderHTMLFileAsPdf("17789.htm", new IronPdf.PdfPrintOptions() { InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2") });
            var OutputPath = "HtmlToPDF.pdf";
            PDF.SaveAs(OutputPath);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputPath);
```